# How to commit a shell command via Java

Tags: java, shell

Is it possible to let your (java) code open a command prompt and enter something within? 
How does the syntax look like?
Thank you

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K [YOUR COMMAND]")`

Comment: thank you, that's excacly what I needed

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the program you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this (`netstat` is only dummy command. you can write whatever you want) ;

```
String command = "cmd.exe /c start " + "netstat";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

after that you can get as data stream from `child` process. Or you can close the `cmd` also with `child.destroy()` method forexample.

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on.